# Issue in pdf to text depending on PDF file's version

Tags: linux, parsing, pdf, text

I'm actually working on **ubuntu** as I'm trying to **parse pdf files to extract text** from them, which I managed to get working (using tesseract for example), BUT as I get a **1.7 pdf file version**, conversion doesn't work (I get a blank page in my 'name.txt' file).

So I was wondering if anyone knew about some magic that can solve my problem regarding this pdf version issue...

I looked pretty much everywhere I could on the web, without seeing similar issues, therefore I came to y'all.

Hope you'll find a way to help me, cause google hasn't been such a friend so far...

Comment: Open that file in Acrobat, select the text and paste it somewhere. Is the text legible?

Comment: Add a link to a PDF which shows the problem.

Comment: When i open the pdf with a viewer, i can copy + paste all the text in it.
I can't give you a copy of that pdf file because it's  protected data... (bills).

The problzem after parsing is that in my .txt i got some very strange characters like if the encoding couldn't be transcripted...